# Play all Audio CD tracks using libvlc in Linux

Tags: c, linux, vlc, libvlc

How play  Audio CD using libvlc in Linux ? All tracks ?
My code play only one track.

```c
vlcInstance = libvlc_new(0,NULL);
vlcMedia = libvlc_media_new_location(vlcInstance, "cdda:///dev/sr0");

libvlc_media_parse(vlcMedia);

vlcMediaList = libvlc_media_list_new(vlcInstance);
libvlc_media_list_add_media(vlcMediaList, vlcMedia);

vlcMediaPlayerList = libvlc_media_list_player_new(vlcInstance);
libvlc_media_list_player_set_media_list(vlcMediaPlayerList,vlcMediaList);

//vlcMediaPlayer = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(vlcMedia);

libvlc_media_list_media(vlcMediaList);
printf("%u\n",libvlc_media_list_count(vlcMediaList));

libvlc_media_list_player_play(vlcMediaPlayerList);

sleep(20);
libvlc_media_list_player_stop(vlcMediaPlayer);
libvlc_media_list_player_release(vlcMediaPlayer);
libvlc_media_release(vlcMedia);
libvlc_release(vlcInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

`libvlc_audio_get_track_count` and `libvlc_audio_set_track` should be able to help.